# Focusing in the right field

Tags: focus, codenameone, lwuit-vkb

in my app, I have a popup-dialog with an editable field where I enter a search string. Thus I have a second container in the dialog, where I show the results and two buttons for OK and CANCEL. When the popup shows, the VKB is activated but the field does not get automatically focused. So I have to press in the field. Is there a solution to make it happen automatically?

Comment: I don't quite understand the description of the issue, do you have some screenshots you can add to clarify what is happening? To start editing a new text field you can just call startEditing() on that field.